# Where is the temporal zone located of DC's Legends of Tomorrow?

Tags: dc, time-travel, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In DC's Legends of Tomorrow, the place which seems to be the 'neutral' place of time is where the legends tend to set the Waverider in when they are not somewhere on a mission. Where is this located and how does the ship access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, the Temporal Zone can be considered the "space" between time and space. As a result, it doesn't really exist "anywhere" physically.

The Waverider goes through the Temporal Zone with the help of a "time drive", whose exact mechanism isn't really explained.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could greatly improve this answer by [edit]ing it to cite any evidence upon which your understanding is based.

Comment: Yes, I got the whole feeling of it not physically existing anywhere. I do wish the whole mechanics of the time drive was explained more in the show, but for now we can just imagine.